# Redirecting main domain but not certain subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Currently I have:

```
Redirect 302 / http://www.example.com
```

Whilst I still want this redirect to happen, I don't want it to redirect them if they go to say `foo.mydomain.com` or any other pages on this sub-domain.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To be more specific in that manner, you'll need to use `RewriteCond / RewriteRule` rather than a simple `Redirect` directive. Do a negative match (`!`) for `foo.mydomain.com` and perform the rewrite. You may match multiple subdomains with an OR group `(foo|other1|other2)`

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect anything except foo.example.com, bar.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(foo|bar)\.example\.com$ [NC]
# Redirect to www.example.com, preserving the URI
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

If you just want to redirect to the root instead of appending the entire URI via `$1`, use the same `RewriteCond` and just do:

```
# Match and redirect everything to the root of www.example.com
RewriteRule ^. http://www.example.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: I had to edit the `RewriteRule` to the following to get it to work: `RewriteRule ^.* http://www.example.com/ [L,R=302]`