# Redirect main domain, but not subdomain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a website with multiple sellers, each seller has is own subdomain. What i want to do is redirect the visitor to login page when visiting main domain (main homepage), but there should be no redirect when visiting subdomain (sellers homepage).

`myproject.com/` redirect-> `myproject.com/login/`

But

`seller.myproject.com/` should not redirect.

I have tried some things with htaccess but i end up redirecting also the subdomains to `seller.myproject.com/login/`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as i'm so bad with regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve your problem using regex, using two occurrence of dots as identification that the user is on seller page. I don't know which language you are using but you can get idea from here.

```
String input="seller.myproject.com/";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(("[a-zA-z0-9]\\.[a-zA-z0-9]\\.com"));
Matcher m=p.matcher(input);
if(m.find())
{
     //don't redirect
}
else
{
     //redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i just found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16886639/8694548

And this works, but now the question how to let all subdomains have this behaviour instead of putting them manually there.

So instead of `!^(foo|bar)\.example\.com$` > `!^(*)\.example\.com$`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay i've got it now, here's whats working for me:

`# Redirect anything except subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.myproject\.com$ [NC]`

`# Redirect to myproject.com/login, preserving the URI
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myproject.com/login/ [L,R=302]`